# UIImagePickerController's top navigation view and bottom toolbar is going behind my view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application in RootViewController i have added a top custom view with titleview & a button similar to UINavigationController and bottom Custom View similar to UITabBar in between i'm having a view(say, contentView) with 320 x 280 dimension view in which i'm adding different different subview as per the user selection of tabs.
In one tab inside my contentView i have a button to open camera, there i'm presenting Camera or PhotoLibrary like

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

but is presenting inside my contentView, so that capture button & camera controls are going behind my navigation bar,below is the snap. Img 1. is normal scenario, but for me its like img.2 
[image: Normal Case (i need it like this)]

[image: In My case]

How to overcome this,Any help is thanks in advance.

Comment: hi can you please tell me that the bar Under HDR ON label in your photo... is this your custom bar or there is any code for this

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ya its a custom bar and for those bar buttons there s code for action,

Comment: can you please tell me , what is the action for camera and video swap button...

Comment: I'm not overriding any of native camera controls i will just open camera & user will take a pic then i will take that pic & process further, here my problem is once i open camera my custom top & bottom bars r hiding camera capture & video swap controls, how to overcome this i tried [super presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; also but of no luck,,,:(

Comment: add your custom view on window.. and camraView in a custom view

Comment: @Rajneesh071 thanks for ur reply,as per my apps design i can't put my custom views to window because on load i have a login screen which is not having any navigation bar or bottom tab bar.Once successful login then only those custom bars i need to show.